# Using Hamcrest with Laravel

Tags: laravel

When I was trying to do a `$string.equalToIgnoringCase()` PHP storm suggested this Hamcrest package. So the usual way for this in Laravel would be including the package in the controller which is creating the relevant UI. So I tried `use Hamcrest\Text\IsEqualIgnoringCase;` 
and/or `Hamcrest` in both App\Http\Controller and in the relevant Controller, still by nothing changes

Comment: Hamcrest is a Java lib. Are you using https://github.com/hamcrest/hamcrest-php ? If so, the docs show a usage example of `Hamcrest_MatcherAssert::assertThat('a', Hamcrest_Matchers::equalToIgnoringCase('A'));`

Comment: No I'm not using anything else come with php 7.2 and laravel 5.5. Made a clean install yesterday. But certainly thanks for the insight on hamcrest php. May be PHP storm has dependencies with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install hamcrest/hamcrest-php with composer, is already installed with laravel/framework, required by phpunit package

Comment: question was about, how to use this in blade templates. Maybe I was not descriptive enough about it